# how to php soap client send request?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am sending parameters to the login function with the following code, but the result is empty. Where am I making mistakes?

```
$url = "http://wsdl.lion-playground.com/GambleServerProxy.svc?wsdl"; 
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$parameters = array("AuthToken"=>"asdsads23123sddds", "Identifier"=>"asdsad22212312", "Password"=>"312312321312321321");
$results = $client->Login("LoginRequest",$parameters);
var_dump($results); // Boş dönüyor ?
```

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client]
>   SoapClient::SoapClient(): 'location' and 'uri' options are required in
>   nonWSDL mode in /home/mornetajans/public_html/demo2/test.php:9

Comment: You might need to explain your problem a bit clearer

Comment: Hİ http://wsdl.lion-playground.com/GambleServerProxy.svc?wsdl send login parameters

Comment: @TürkwebYazılımveDanışmanlık what language do you speak?

Comment: I do not know :(

Comment: Türkçe konuş? @TürkwebYazılımveDanışmanlık

Comment: Türkçe yazdım...